# Fill a spinner with data from a mysql table using kotlin

Tags: android, mysql, kotlin

i want to fill a spinner with data from my mysql table, I am using android studio and kotlin. When I launch the application I have this message "application has stopped".
My kotlin code

```
spinner_bac = findViewById(R.id.spinner_bac)
    val url = "http://192.168.43.5/android/remplissage_bac.php"
    val rq: RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    val jor= JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null, Response.Listener{ response ->
               val jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("bacc")
               for(i in 0..response.length()-1){
                   val jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                   val nomBacc = jsonObject.getString("label_bacc")
                   listeBacc.add(nomBacc)
                   baccAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this@MainActivity,
                       android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item, listeBacc
                   )
                   baccAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                   spinner_bac.adapter = baccAdapter
               }
    },Response.ErrorListener{error ->
       fun onErrorResponse(error: VolleyError) {
       }
    })
    rq.add(jor)
```

My query

```
<?php
require_once "connexion.php";
$sql="select * from bacc";
if (!$conn->query($sql)) {
    echo "erreur de connexion a la base de donnee";
}
else{
    $resultat=$conn->query($sql);
    if ($resultat->num_rows > 0) {
        $return_arr['bacc'] = array();
        while ($row=$resultat->fetch_array()) {
            array_push($return_arr['bacc'],array(
                'bacc_id'=>$row['bacc_id'],
                'label_bacc'=>$row['label_bacc']
            ));
        }
        echo json_encode($return_arr);
    }
}?>
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message that you are getting from the debugger?

Comment: The application runs without errors and is installed normally in the emulator and it is when launching that it says: "application has stopped"

Comment: This means that a crash occurred because of a bug in your code, you should run your application in debug mode from Android Studio and check the console for error messages.

Comment: I run my application in debug mode and I have this error **java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table
Could not perform incremental compilation: Could not connect to Kotlin compile daemon
Could not connect to kotlin daemon. Using fallback strategy.**